# free jqgrid 4.8.0 colModel editoptions - dynamic values from query

Tags: jqgrid

I am working with Coldfusion and jqgrid.

Is there a way to populate the colModel editoptions dynamically from query results?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set dynamically the options like `1:female;2:male`, then I suppose that you fill grid with data which contains 1 or 2 in the specified column. So you have to use `formatter: "select"` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select)). Thus you should be able to set the properties like below

```js
{name: "sex", formatter: "select", editoptions: { value: "1:female;2:male" }}
```

If you need to set such options dynamically, that you want to load the information about `editoptions.value` from the server.

The most native callback which you can use for it is `beforeProcessing`. The callback will be processed **before** the data returned from the server will be displayed using the formatter. So one can make any changes of `formatoptions` or `editoptions`.

If the server response looks now like

```json
{
    "rows": [
        {"id": 123, "name": "John", "sex": "2"},
        {"id": 456, "name": "Mary", "sex": "1"}
    ]
}
```

then you can extend the data of the server response to the following

```json
{
    "rows": [
        {"id": 123, "name": "John", "sex": "2"},
        {"id": 456, "name": "Mary", "sex": "1"}
    ],
    "colModelExtentions": {
        "sex": {"formatter": "select", "editoptions": {"value": "1:female;2:male"}}
    }
}
```

In the way you specify some changes of specific items of the `colModel` directly inside of the server response. The implementation of the `beforeProcessing` callback which process such data can looks like

```js
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var cmName, cmExt = data.colModelExtentions, $self = $(this),
        p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    for (cmName in cmExt) {
        // enumerate properties of colModelExtentions like sex
        if (cmExt.hasOwnProperties(cmName)) {
            $self.jqGrid("setColProp", cmName, cmExt[cmName]);
        }
    }
}
```

and to define the `"sex"` columns in `colModel` like

```js
{name: "sex", width: 50}
```

You will find more details about the scenario in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935). You can extend the information which return the server. In the case you can need to call `setColWidth` or `setLabel` additionally to apply dynamically the column width and the text of the column header.